# How to store/append the previous values when clicking next

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to append an array based on the user input.
So I have 3 questions and the user can select one or multiple answers, and when clicking Next this input should be stored into useState.

The code I have it's working, but if I have 2 questions with one (or multiple) answers it will store them into setSelected or setMultipleSelected with only the last input of the user, forgetting the first input from the first question.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import { UserAuth } from "../../context/AuthContext";

interface LessonQuiz {
    courseID:string;
    lessonID:string;
    resource: DetailedQuizInterface[];
  }
 
 

  function classNames(...classes: any) {
    return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}
interface DetailedQuizInterface {
  question: string;
  answers: string[];
  multipleAnswer: boolean;
  correctAnswer: string | string[]
  points: number;
}

interface AnswerIds {
  id: number,
  answer: string | string[]
}

function LessonQuiz(props: LessonQuiz) {
   
    let [handler, setHandler] = useState<Boolean>(true);
    
    const [selected, setSelected] =  useState<Array<string>>([]);
    const [multipleSelected, setMultipleSelected] =  useState<Array<string>>([]);
    const [previous, setPrevious] =  useState({});

    const {user} = UserAuth();
   
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(0);
    const a:any = [];

    const handleChange = (event: any) => {
      const { checked, value } = event.currentTarget;
      if( props.resource[clicked].multipleAnswer === false) {
        setSelected(
          prev => checked
            ? [value]
            : prev.filter(val => val !== value)

        );
      }
      else {
        setMultipleSelected(
          prev => checked
            ? [...prev, value]
            : prev.filter(val => val !== value)
        );
      }

       
  };

 


 
function next() {

  setClicked(clicked+1)
} 

function prev() {
 
  setClicked(clicked-1)
} 



 function handleSubmit(e:any){
  console.log(selected)
   
  e.preventDefault();
  
   //send to db after storing
     
}

//}
 


  return (
        
   <div className="bg-white py-32 px-6 lg:px-8">
  

   <div className="mx-auto max-w-3xl text-base leading-7 text-gray-700">
     <p className="text-base font-semibold leading-7 text-indigo-600"> </p>
     <h1 className="mt-2  text-l font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-l">AAA</h1>
     <div className="mt-10 max-w-2xl">
 

 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  
<>

<div className="space-y-12" >
        <div className="border-b border-gray-900/10 pb-12">
          
          <p className="mt-1 text-2xl leading-6 text-gray-600">
          {props.resource[clicked].question}
          </p>
         
          { props.resource[clicked].multipleAnswer === false ? (
             <p className="mt-5 text-sm leading-6 text-gray-600">
               Choose one answer.
             </p>
           )
           :
           (<p className="mt-5 text-sm leading-6 text-gray-600">
             Choose one or multiple answers.
           </p>
         )
         
        } 
         

           
        </div>   
        <div className="border-b border-gray-900/10 pb-12">
          

          <div className="mt-10 space-y-10">
            
            <fieldset>
             
              <div className="mt-6 space-y-6">
                
                    
                     { 
                     
                    
                      props.resource[clicked].answers.map((item) => (

                        <div className="relative flex gap-x-3" key={item} >
                        <div className="flex h-6 items-center">
                      
                         
                          <div>
                          {  
                          props.resource[clicked].multipleAnswer === false ? 
                          (
  
                            <input 
                            id={item}
                            value={item}
                            type="radio" 
                            className="h-4 w-4 border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-600"
  
                            checked={selected.some(val => val.toString() === item)  }
                            onChange={handleChange} 
                          />
  
                          ) : 
                          (
  
                            <input 
                            id={item}
                            value={item}
                            type="checkbox" 
                            className="h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-600"
  
                            checked={multipleSelected.some(val => val.toString() === item)  }
                            onChange={handleChange} 
                          />
                          )
                          }
                          </div>

                          </div>
                             <div className="text-sm leading-6">
                               <label htmlFor="comments" className="font-medium text-gray-900">
                                 {item}
                               </label>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        

                      ))
                     }    
                        
                  
         



              </div>
            </fieldset>
             
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="mt-6 flex items-center justify-end gap-x-6">
         

      </div>
      
      
      </>

      <div className="md:text-right">
    
      {

     
     
                    clicked+1 === props.resource.length ? (
                       
                        handler === true ? ( <button
                          type="submit"
                          onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event)}
                          className="rounded-md text-left bg-indigo-600 ml-4 px-3 py-2   text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"
                        >
                          Submit answers
                        </button>
                        ) :
                        (
                        <>
                        </>
                        )
                       

                    ) : (

                      
                  <></>
                    )
    }
    </div>           
                
 

    
 
    </form>

    <div className="col">
    <a className={classNames(  'text-gray-300','group  items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md' )}> 
                    {`Questions: ` + (clicked+1) + `/` + props.resource.length } 
                 </a>

    {
 
                    clicked+1 !== props.resource.length ? (
                 
                           
                      clicked !== 0 ? (
                        <>                        <button className={classNames(  ' bg-gray-600 text-white mr-3' ,  'group  items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md' )}

                        onClick={prev}
                      
                              >
                                Prev
                              </button>

                              <button className={classNames(  ' bg-gray-600 text-white' ,  'group mr-2 items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md' )}

                            onClick={next}

                                  >
                                    Next
                                  </button>
                              </>



                      ) : (
                        <>
                             <button className={classNames(  ' bg-gray-600 text-white' ,  'group mr-2 items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md' )}

                          onClick={next}

                                >
                                  Next
                                </button>
                        </> )
                      
                      

                   


                      ) : (
                       
                        <button className={classNames(  ' bg-gray-600 text-white' ,  'group  items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md' )}

                                onClick={prev}
                      
                              >
                                Prev
                              </button>
                      )
                              
          }
</div>
     </div>
   </div>
        
     
 </div>
 

    )
}

export default LessonQuiz;
```

Now I have 2 questions that have one answer to be selected and another question with multiple options. If the user selects something in the first question (the one with the one option), the value will be stored, but if the user goes to the next question (and this one is the same with one option) the previous input is forgotten.

[image]